# Subscript numbers in chemical formulae from selection

Tags: vba, ms-word

I often find chemical formulae in my documents that require the numbers to be made subscript. e.g. H2O should be H<sub>2</sub>O and H2SO4 should be H<sub>2</sub>SO<sub>4</sub>.  I am trying to write a macro that will take numbers from a highlighted selection and subscript numerical values.  I am not very good at programming.  I have tried variations on the following:

```vb
Sub SubscriptNumbers()
    
    Dim Char As String
  
    For Each Char In Selection.Characters
             
            If Char >= "0" And Char <= "9" Then
                Char = Char.Font.Subscript
            End If
        
    Next Char
    
End Sub
```

But I get confusing errors (Compile Error: `For Each control variable must be Variant or Object`; but if I change Char to variant, it runs without error but doesn't appear to do anything). I know that there is an aversion from people in the know about using 'Select' but my doc will likely contain lots of other numbers that should not be made subscript.

Comment: It is not very helpful to say "But I get confusing errors". It would be helpful if you had said "I get this error: [*complete error text*] in this [*description of when the error occurs*] situation". Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: @TomBrunberg added additional detail

Comment: Thank you! Btw, how do you trigger the `SubscriptNumbers()` sub? (I must confess, I have not worked much with VBA in Word)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although not stated in the documentation to loop through `Characters` you need to declare `Char As Range`. You then need to check if `Char.Text` is a number. There is a built-in function for doing this - `IsNumeric`. Finally you need to set `.Font.Subscript` to either true or false.

```
Sub SubscriptNumbers()
   Dim Char As Range
  
   For Each Char In Selection.Characters
      If IsNumeric(Char.Text) Then
         Char.Font.Subscript = True
      End If
   Next Char
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! This simple task was driving me crazy. Your explanation that you have to declare Char as Range in VBA was the missing puzzle piece. After reading the next answer, I made a tiny modification to the code to ignore existing superscripts for isotopes.

Answer (score 2):

The following macro will search the active document (or just a selected range) for chemical formulae (e.g. H2O, C5H8(N2S)4, 3(CaO)•2(SiO2)•4(H2O)(gel) + 3Ca(OH)2) and power expressions (e.g. 100m2), superscripting/subscripting the numbers as appropriate. Unless you're working with isotopes, the results should be correct - you'll need to apply the isotope superscripting yourself (if the numbers are already superscripted, they’ll be left alone).

If your document has other alphanumeric strings in which a non-superscripted number follows a letter (eg Table cell references), you’ll need to select only the range(s) containing the text to be converted and answer ‘No’ to the prompt.

```
Sub ChemPwrFmt()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim RngSel As Range, RngNum As Range, RngTmp As Range, bState As Boolean
Select Case MsgBox("Do you want to process the whole document?", _
    vbYesNoCancel + vbQuestion, "Chemical/Power Formatter")
  Case vbYes
    bState = True
  Case vbNo
    bState = False
  Case vbCancel
    End
End Select
Set RngSel = Selection.Range
With ActiveDocument.Range
  If bState = False Then .Start = RngSel.Start
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Text = "[A-Za-z)][0-9]{1,}"
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Forward = True
  End With
  Do While .Find.Execute = True
    Set RngNum = .Characters.Last
    If bState = False Then
      If RngNum.InRange(RngSel) = False Then Exit Do
    End If
    Set RngTmp = .Words.Last
    RngTmp.MoveStartUntil " ", wdBackward
    If LCase(RngTmp.Text) = RngTmp.Text Then
      RngNum.Font.Superscript = True
    ElseIf RngNum.Font.Superscript = False Then
      RngNum.Font.Subscript = True
    End If
    .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
  Loop
End With
RngSel.Select
Set RngTmp = Nothing: Set RngNum = Nothing: Set RngSel = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```